# Метод API VK написать сообщение сообществу

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Подскажите, пожалуйста есть ли метод API VK написать сообщение сообществу от пользователя, перелопатил всю документацию в вк, так и не нашел. может кто сталкивался

Answer (score 1):

В каком смысле от пользователя сообществу? тип если я тебя правильно понял то ты можешь использовать messages.send

```
peer_id идентификатор назначения. 

Для сообщества: 
-id сообщества.
```